# No size difference between Hadoop SequenceFile and TextFile?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, avro, parquet, sequencefile

I am trying to compress my Spark output files and I found that SequenceFile's can be used for it.

I saved the file in Java like that:

```
JavaPairRDD<Text, Text> result = ...
result.coalesce(1).saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(outputPath.toString() + ".seq", Text.class, Text.class, SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);
```

However, I couldn't get any size difference between saveAsTextFile output and this sequence file output. I have seen different methods to create Sequence files but most of them using Scala and I should use Java, so I used this method.

result pair rdd is something like:

```
1, 123.456, 123.457, 123.458, ...
2, 123.789, 123.790, 123.791, ...
...
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or do I understand sequence file concept completely wrong.

By the way, this output file then be used in R for data analysis. And I can't use SparkSQL, Dataframes etc.

If you have other suggestions like Parquet or Avro, where I won't use DataFrames, that would be so nice.

I just need to compress my files and they should be decompressed or directly used over Hadoop API's or R libraries.

Comment: Why do you expect size difference? Sequence files are not very efficient from the beginning and even with compression enabled, your data doesn't look like something that could benefit much from compression.

Comment: Because I was looking for how can I compress my files, even higher read/write speed would be beneficial for the project. So I just came across with SequenceFiles, Parquet and Avro( I read as sequence files enables compression, maybe the sources I read these are wrong). I wanted to start with the simplest one, SequenceFiles.

I read lots of topics over here, and I stuck between Scala and SparkSQL use cases.

Comment: The files go up to 3.5Gb, so I guess compression is asked for storage. Anyway I need to decompress them to use. But if there is a middleware which flattens the compressed file on air, that would be also useful for my case. So that I am open for any suggestions.

Comment: Question could be confusing, because I just jump directly into this project, before that I had no experience on distributed computing side of big-data projects and I am trying to do my best with only core Spark knowledge on Java

Comment: For starters, I would suggest not doing `coalesce(1)` as that defeats the purpose of parallelism with Spark. Secondly, do you really need a sequencefile? Spark's default output format is Parquet, which you can use Snappy compression with... If you need to use R, then there's SparkR, or you can expose Spark Thrift Server or Hive to write SQL queries directly on those files from R code

Comment: I used coalesce because I need a single output at the end. I don't know how else I can create a single output.
For the parquet, the project is using only Spark Core, and as I know, I need to used dataframes to creae parquet. We won't need a columnar data, every time the whole data will be used, so I'm conidering Avro also. If I won't need SparkSQL for Parquet, I will check it out.

Comment: We are also thinking about to use SparkR but we have limited time, I guess it will also take a time to get it